# Using jQuery load()

Tags: jquery, django

I'm using Django-1.4.5 and I'm trying to load txt file in my page using jQuery load() function. But instead of text, it loads my entire page once again. I've got jQuery function in base.html:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#text_id").load('sometext.txt');
    });
```

And I call it in div in another page which extends bese.html:

```
<div id="text_id">
    Some text<br />
</div>
```

I don't understand this behaviour. I'm new to Django and jQuery, so probably I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: your jquery code should work even i don't know django. Your problem come from somewhere else.

Comment: How does your `urls.py` look like? You're probably not even entering a view that serves you your .txt file.

Comment: You can check if your text file is accessible by url in browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The mistake was in my views.py file. It works now